# UIScrollview won't scroll horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a project where I'm trying to scroll horizontally using a `UIScrollView` however, I can't get it to scroll.

The scrollview was added through Interface Builder, and after that it was set up in `viewWillAppear()` this is what I did:

```
let overview = CourseDetails(course: self.course, type: holes, frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 812, height: 100))
scrollView.addSubview(overview)
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 812, height: 100)
overview.frame.size.width = 812
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

The scrollview has a content view width of 812, while the UIViews frame is 345 in width...

Is there a step I'm missing in the whole scrollview scenario?

Comment: What is overview and why are you setting its width after adding it to scroll view?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the inspector information for the scrollview, autolayouts at play - or may be isolated project code itself?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set the `content size` of `UIScrollView`. You can set it in interface builder.

Follow these steps in `interface builder`:

1. Add a `UIScrollView` in your view hierarchy
2. Add a `UIView` as subview of `UIScrollView` which will be the content view of `UIScrollView`. Now You will add all other views for which you want scrolling as `subviews` of this `contentView`.
3. Now set constraints for both `UIScrollView` and it's content `view`(UIView).
   For `UIScrollView` set `Leading, Trailing ,Top and Bottom` constraints to it's `superView`.
   For `contentView` of `UIScrollView`, set `leading, trailing, top and bottom` constraint pins to `UIScrollView.`

   Now the tricky part for setting `content size` of the `UIScrollView`. Set the `width` and `height` constraint for the `contentView`.
   You have to set the `width` and `height` equal to `UIScrollView`. To set these two constraints, make selection on `contentView` and then control + drag to `UIScrollView`  and then choose equal `width` and equal `height`.

   Now set the constraint priority to low(250) of `width` if you want horizontal scrolling or of `height` if you want vertical scrolling.

Comment: Ut doesn't make a difference for me. The scrollview's stilll static

Answer (score 0):

I think, CourseDetails view generation arises problem. I check this using following code:

```
let overview = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 812, height: 100))
overview.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
scrollView.addSubview(overview)
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: overview.frame.size.width, height: 100)
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

It's working. Please share CourseDetails view information for resolving this issue otherwise it's difficult to trace.

Please check interface builder Scroll View settings:

```
 1. Enable check mark for scrolling enabled [Scrolling Section]
 2. Enable check mark for user interaction enabled [View Section]
```

Comment: Both of your two points are enabled. What information would you need vant the `CourseDetails`?